# Coral AI Dev Board cannot connect via USB, after using WiFi connection

Tags: ubuntu, google-coral, mendel-os

I have some problems with the board, I can no longer connect it via USB to the host.

Initially, I set it to work via wireless network, but now I need via usb cable.

When I run the command 'mdt shell' from host, 'Unable to find any devices on your local network segments' is displayed as response. The board is not recognized by host when I connect it and use a cable that supports data transfer, as well.

I also tried to disable wifi connection from the board, but still can not connect via usb.

Can you help me please with some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Yes, I can't figure out if I need to reflash the board or not. Currently, I'm using the board only via Wifi :(

Comment: Can you connect the board via USB-C cable and run "mdt shell 192.168.100.2" from your host machine and share the output here ?